# How to find if a tif image is color or black and white in java

Tags: java, tiff

I am trying to check if a tiff image is in color or not. I have searched for the solution everywhere but non of the solutions seem to work . Following is the code that i am using which is giving me a null pointer exception. It seems the bufferedImage object is not able to read the tiff image. Any other method to find color of tiff will also do.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\desktop_backup\\2015-10-26\\PDF\\TIFF\\150_TIF_COL.tif"));
Raster ras = image.getRaster();
int elem = ras.getNumDataElements();
System.out.println("Number of Elems: " + elem);
```

Comment: Are you using the Java Advanced Imaging API? Looks like that might be required for working with TIF format.  See: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-142003.html

Comment: can you give the exact error as it may help

Comment: Here's an [alternative to JAI](http://haraldk.github.io/TwelveMonkeys/) for reading TIFF tiles (disclaimer, I'm the author).

Comment: PS: If you don't need to inspect all the pixel values, but simply rely on the color model (ie. number of elements, like above), you don't need to decode the image. Either look at the TIFF metadata, or get the `ImageTypeSpecifier` from the TIFF `ImageReader` instance. This should be much faster than fully decoding the image.

Comment: Hi I have tried JAI as well as @haraldK but somehow I am not able to make it work for me due to reference problems. Is it possible for you to give me links to the JARs which I can import and code or links to documentation where I can find how to check the color of the tif

Comment: @sameersingh What do you mean by "due to reference problems"? I gave you a link to my page above, which does have links to JARs for download.